# Call Google Play Developer API from Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to develop a server-side validation of my users' in-app purchases and subscriptions as [recommended](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#validating-purchase-server), and I want to use Firebase Functions for that. Basically it has to be an HTTP trigger function that receives a purchase token, calls the Play Developer API to verify the purchase, and then does something with the result.

However, calling many of the Google APIs (including [Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)) requires non-trivial authorization. Here's how I understand the required setup:

1. There has to be a GCP project with Google Play Developer API v2 enabled.
2. It should be a separate project, since there can be only one linked to Play Store in the Google Play Console.
3. My Firebase Functions project must somehow authenticate to that other project. I figured that using a Service Account is most suitable in this server-to-server scenario.
4. Finally, my Firebase Functions code must somehow obtain authentication token (hopefully JWT?) and finally make an API call to get a subscription status.

The problem is that absolutely no human-readable documentation or guidance on that is existent. Given that ingress traffic in Firebase is included in the free plan (so I assume they encourage using Google APIs from Firebase Functions), that fact is pretty disappointing. I've managed to find some bits of info here and there, but having too little experience with Google APIs (most of which required simply using an api key), I need help with putting it together.

Here's what I figured out so far:

1. I got a GCP project linked to the Play Store and with the API enabled. For some reason though, trying to test it in APIs Explorer results in an error "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console".
2. I made a Service Account and exported a JSON key, which contains the key to produce a JWT.
3. I also set up read permissions for that Service Account in Play Console.
4. I found a [Node.JS client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) for Google APIs, which is in alpha and has very sparse documentation (e.g. there's no obvious documentation on how to authenticate with JWT, and no samples on how to call the android publisher API). At the moment I'm struggling with that. Unfortunately I'm not super-comfortable with reading JS library code, especially when the editor doesn't provide the possibility to jump to highlighted functions' sources.

I'm pretty surprised this hasn't been asked or documented, because verifying in-app purchases from Firebase Functions seems like a common task. Has anyone successfully done it before, or maybe the Firebase team will step in to answer?

Comment: Hey I would like to ask you some questions regarding this. Did you created seperate service account or you can use firebase json for public and private keys ?

Comment: @ABDevelopers Play Store API can only be accessed from *one* GCP project (Firebase projects are also backed by GCP projects), so it makes sense to create not just an account, but a totally separate _GCP project_ just for accessing the API. Actually this has been simplified lately: you just have to follow the instructions in Google Play Console -> Settings -> API access. Of course you can link your existing Firebase project instead, but when you eventually want to access the API from another app, you'll probably have to reconfigure.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort towards the question and answer and It really helped me. Do you have any idea about firebase cron jobs ?

Comment: @ABDevelopers As far as I know they don't have those. You can either set up an App Engine instance within Google Cloud as suggested in [this Firebase blog entry](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html), or use some external service, e.g. cron-job.org, to make HTTP requests at desired times, which you can then handle in your Functions. This is a separate topic though.

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49346136/5482999

Comment: @Racu that's funny that I answered my own question at about the same time you answered that one. Well, I already implemented it my way, and I'm kinda happy that I did it without the Google APIs client but with vanilla HTTP.

Comment: @Actine yep I actually found that interesting 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I also ditched the heavyweight client library and just coded those few requests manually.

Notes:

- The same applies to any Node.js server environment. You still need the key file of a separate service account to mint a JWT and the two steps to call the API, and Firebase is no different.
- The same applies to other APIs that require authentication as well — differing only in `scope` field of the JWT.
- There are [a few APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google) that don't need you to exchange the JWT for an access token — you can mint a JWT and provide it directly in `Authentication: Bearer`, without a round trip to OAuth backend.

After you've got the JSON file with the private key for a Service Account that's linked to Play Store, the code to call the API is like this (adjust to your needs). Note: I used `request-promise` as a nicer way to do `http.request`.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const keyData = require('./key.json');         // Path to your JSON key file
const request = require('request-promise');

/** 
 * Exchanges the private key file for a temporary access token,
 * which is valid for 1 hour and can be reused for multiple requests
 */
function getAccessToken(keyData) {
  // Create a JSON Web Token for the Service Account linked to Play Store
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher' },
    keyData.private_key,
    {
      algorithm: 'RS256',
      expiresIn: '1h',
      issuer: keyData.client_email,
      subject: keyData.client_email,
      audience: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
    }
  );

  // Make a request to Google APIs OAuth backend to exchange it for an access token
  // Returns a promise
  return request.post({
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion': token
    },
    transform: body => JSON.parse(body).access_token
  });
}

/**
 * Makes a GET request to given URL with the access token
 */
function makeApiRequest(url, accessToken) {
  return request.get({
    url: url,
    auth: {
      bearer: accessToken
    },
    transform: body => JSON.parse(body)
  });
}

// Our test function
exports.testApi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // TODO: process the request, extract parameters, authenticate the user etc

  // The API url to call - edit this
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/${packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/tokens/${token}`;

  getAccessToken(keyData)
    .then(token => {
      return makeApiRequest(url, token);
    })
    .then(response => {
      // TODO: process the response, e.g. validate the purchase, set access claims to the user etc.
      res.send(response);
      return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

[These](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) are the docs I followed.

Comment: HI @actine, currently I am getting "permission denied" error (The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation).  Is this a problem with my service account.json or something else? Please let me know how do you create your service-account.json ( roles etc ..)

Comment: @thomasbabuj double-check if that service account is the one connected to Google Play Console, and that it has necessary permissions (e.g. for billing you can grant Finance role). You set the roles on Settings -> API access -> Service accounts (last table on the page) -> Grant access / View permissions

Comment: thanks for your response. I was able to solve my issue by updating the roles for the service-account email id in play console. thanks again.

Comment: Actine, this might be exactly what I'm looking for.  Wow, documentation seems horrible.  Been stuck for days.  I am confused about what you are importing, what a jwt is.... would you consider making a version of this where all the code is one file here?  Also, why I don't I see an exports.xxxxx as this is supposed to be Functions - is this your index.js file?

Comment: @JeffPadgett Yes, this is the index.js, the `exports.testApi` is there. Not the best structured code, but okay enough for me and for illustrating the answer. `jwt` and `request` variables are imported npm modules. JWT is basically a way to authenticate (quite an ingenious really) — read [here](http://jwt.io). This _is_ all the code in one file (except the npm modules and the `key.json` you download from your GCP console).

Comment: Ah, so in other words, I could run "npm install jsonwebtoken", and "npm install request-promise", to get those modules, correct?  Also, is this just for OAuth, and therefore would not be appropriate for a service account?

Comment: @JeffPadgett this is **specifically** for the service account. The `key.json` is your service account key that you dl from GCP console. It's just that auth API is the same one. Regarding npm, yes, that's correct.

Comment: I always get a 404 when calling makeApiRequest

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by changing v2 to v3

Comment: my firebase function refuses to deploy when using this code

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a slightly quicker way to do this... or at least... more simply.

To support scaling and keep index.ts from growing out of control... I have all the functions and globals in the index file but all the actual events are handled by handlers.  Easier to maintain.

So here's my index.ts (I heart type safety):

```
//my imports so you know
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { SubscriptionEventHandler } from "./subscription/subscription-event-handler";

// honestly not 100% sure this is necessary 
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: 'dburl'
});

const db = admin.database();

//reference to the class that actually does the logic things
const subscriptionEventHandler = new SubscriptionEventHandler(db);

//yay events!!!
export const onSubscriptionChange = functions.pubsub.topic('subscription_status_channel').onPublish((message, context) => {
    return subscriptionEventHandler.handle(message, context);
});
//aren't you happy this is succinct??? I am!
```

Now... for the show!

```
// importing like World Market
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {SubscriptionMessageEvent} from "./model/subscription-message-event";
import {androidpublisher_v3, google, oauth2_v2} from "googleapis";
import {UrlParser} from "../utils/url-parser";
import {AxiosResponse} from "axios";
import Schema$SubscriptionPurchase = androidpublisher_v3.Schema$SubscriptionPurchase;
import Androidpublisher = androidpublisher_v3.Androidpublisher;

// you have to get this from your service account... or you could guess
const key = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "not going to tell you",
    "private_key_id": "really not going to tell you",
    "private_key": "okay... I'll tell you",
    "client_email": "doesn't matter",
    "client_id": "some number",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "another url"
};

//don't guess this...  this is right
const androidPublisherScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";

// the handler
export class SubscriptionEventHandler {
    private ref: admin.database.Reference;

    // so you don't need to do this... I just did to log the events in the db
    constructor(db: admin.database.Database) {
        this.ref = db.ref('/subscriptionEvents');
    }

    // where the magic happens
    public handle(message, context): any {
        const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()) as SubscriptionMessageEvent;

        // if subscriptionNotification is truthy then we're solid here
        if (message.json.subscriptionNotification) {
            // go get the the auth client but it's async... so wait
            return google.auth.getClient({
                scopes: androidPublisherScope,
                credentials: key
            }).then(auth => {
                //yay!  success!  Build android publisher!
                const androidPublisher = new Androidpublisher({
                    auth: auth
                });

                // get the subscription details
                androidPublisher.purchases.subscriptions.get({
                    packageName: data.packageName,
                    subscriptionId: data.subscriptionNotification.subscriptionId,
                    token: data.subscriptionNotification.purchaseToken
                }).then((response: AxiosResponse<Schema$SubscriptionPurchase>) => {
                    //promise fulfilled... grandma would be so happy
                    console.log("Successfully retrieved details: " + response.data.orderId);
                }).catch(err => console.error('Error during retrieval', err));
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Test event... logging test');
            return this.ref.child('/testSubscriptionEvents').push(data);
        }
    }
}
```

There are few model classes that help:

```
export class SubscriptionMessageEvent {
    version: string;
    packageName: string;
    eventTimeMillis: number;
    subscriptionNotification: SubscriptionNotification;
    testNotification: TestNotification;
}

export class SubscriptionNotification {
    version: string;
    notificationType: number;
    purchaseToken: string;
    subscriptionId: string;
}
```

So that's how we do that thing.

Comment: Hi. Great answer but I always get the error " The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.". Any solutions?

Comment: Thanks.  You need to make sure your service account for your Google Cloud Functions is registered with your Google Play Developer account.  Answer can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has-not-been-l

Comment: Yes, that was not working for some reason but after I did everything all over again using a brand new GCP project, it worked. Now, I have logically question - In the response, we do not get any information about the user who purchased the subscription. How do we find out user's info from the purchase token? I liked around and found that a field called `developerPayload` is there but it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: You should have a copy of the token locally on the device.  You can save it on the device and then use it to reference the copy your server has.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `401, Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.` even after you followed all the steps described in the accepted answer, there are a few things you need to check.

- The service account (`Google Cloud Console -> IAM & Admin -> Service accounts`) you created should be mapped to the app you are working with. In other words, `Google Play Console (*not* Google Cloud Console) -> Users and permissions -> Invite new users`.
- Enter the service account's email. Also, make sure to add your app to `App permissions` tab and select the following in `Account permissions` tab.

  [x] View app information and download bulk reports (read-only)

  [x] View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses

  [x] Manage orders and subscriptions
- If you are accessing in-app products or subscriptions that were created before the service account, you *might* need to wait a while before the service account can access them. If you want the instant gratification, just make a small change in the product's description.

Here is an example that retrieves a purchase status (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get) using `express` and `googleapis`.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account_key.json");
const {google} = require("googleapis");

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/products", async (request, response) => {
    const {packageName, productId, token} = request.body;
    const auth = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        key: serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
    });
    const androidPublisher = google.androidpublisher({
        version: "v3",
        auth: auth
    });

    try {
        await auth.authorize();

        const product = await androidPublisher.purchases.products.get({
            packageName: packageName,
            productId: productId,
            token: token
        }); 
        response.json({product});
    } catch (error) {
        response.send(`${error.type}: ${error.message}`);
    }
});

exports.app = onRequest(app);
```