# API explorer is loading without response

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use the API explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) by inputting my package name, subscription id and the token I get from my in app purchase. But once I do I get a loading spinnen that never stops or gives any feedback.

[image]

I currently can do in app purchases in my app and I get the purchase details. But I want to verify them in my backend.

The subscriptionId I used is the product id from my subscription that I got from the play console.

[image]

I am trying to do this with the API explorer because of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148137/invalid-value-at-gaxios-request-srv-node-modules-googleapis-common-node-modul) . So I can test if it works.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Why don't I get a response?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the `?` sign next to credentials. You will get a cURL, HTTP and Javascript example for your request to fill in your API-Keys and stuff. Did you try this?

Did you follow these steps: [Am I getting the steps right for verifying a user's Android in-app subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427479/am-i-getting-the-steps-right-for-verifying-a-users-android-in-app-subscription)